# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded or Contract code size over limit, yet this is just a copy of a contract already deployed

Tags: truffle, remix, contract-deployment

I am trying to create a DeFi app that works with PAXG gold token. But in order to do this, I need to first be able to deploy a copy of PAXG on my local testnet (Ganache).

I have forked the [github](https://github.com/paxosglobal/paxos-gold-contract) and downloaded the code to my desktop. However, PAXGImplementation is causing a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" message when Truffle tries to compile it and  "Contract code size over limit" message when Remix tries to deploy it.

From what I understand, these errors are telling me that there is an infinite loop somewhere in the code. But this same code is deployed to Ethereum and running on the mainnet right now.

I've also checked the code to make sure its verified, and the verified version can be found [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x74271f2282ed7ee35c166122a60c9830354be42a#code). It's identical to the github version in contracts/flattened/PAXGImplementation.sol. Also, I am using the flattened version of the contracts when I try to deploy. I've removed the "zeppelin" folder and moved the contracts from the "flattened" subfolder into the "contracts" folder, then deleted the "flattened" folder. This was to make sure that the error wasn't caused by a bug in Truffle that causes deployment to fail when contracts import each other.

So basically, Remix and Truffle are both telling me that there is an infinite loop in the PAXGImplementation code - and yet, this code has been deployed to Ethereum. It's obviously not possible for both of these things to be true. So I must be misunderstanding something.

Does anyone know what might be going on here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Error "Contract code size over limit" means what it says: the contract is too large to be deployed to the blockchain. Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306038/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-when-try-compilation-in-solidity

Comment: Then how did it get deployed to the blockchain here [link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x74271f2282ed7ee35c166122a60c9830354be42a#code)? If the contract is too large to be deployed to the blockchain, the devs should have been unable to deploy it. Yet there it is.